# Bitbucket clone fails with out of memory error - “fatal: out of memory, malloc failed

Tags: ubuntu, bitbucket

I'm attempting to clone a large (1.2GB) Git repository to Ubuntu 16.04 with 1998MB of RAM. I am using Ubuntu terminal, and using the HTTPS protocol to clone ('git@bitbucket.org: user@host.com:/my/repo').

The clone fails with this message:

fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocate 368077969 bytes).

Is this issue is happened due to the size of RAM?

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid HTTPS URL, and it also doesn't look like a valid SSH URL. HTTPS URLs for Bitbucket should be something like `https://user@bitbucket.org/owner/repo.git`, and SSH URLs for Bitbucket should be something like `user@bitbucket.org:owner/repo.git` (though `git@bitbucket.org` will work too).

Comment: It is working now. I just increased the memory size of server.